# Laravel 5 multiple pagination in a single page

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

I have a page with two table displaying different data from different database. I am able to do the pagination for both table, but when I click page 2 for table 1, table 2 will also redirect to page 2. How can I make the table 2 stay in page 1 while table 1 go to page 2 when I click on page 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see in the laravel core, then you will see paginate function something like this

```
/**
 * Paginate the given query.
 *
 * @param  int  $perPage
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @param  string  $pageName
 * @param  int|null  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
{
    $total = $this->query->getCountForPagination();
    $this->query->forPage(
        $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName),
        $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage()
    );
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($this->get($columns), $total, $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => $pageName,
    ]);
}
```

Now in above function you can pass $pagename to make both pagination working separately like below

```
$collectionA = ModelA::paginate(4, ['*'], 'pagination_a');
$collectionB = ModelB::paginate(4, ['*'], 'pagination_b');
```

Or You can also use setPageName function for this

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help, it's working now. You saved my day.